# How to write linq query from sql query using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a table with two columns like BookingArrivedEnquiredTime with **varchar** datatype and datetime BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime. When I execute this query in SQL Server the result give perfect with time sorted order 
the sql query will be like

```
select BookingArrivedEnquiredTime from BookingArriveds where BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime='2015-02-17 00:00:00.000' 
order by CAST(('01/01/2000 ' + BookingArrivedEnquiredTime) AS DATETIME)
```

and it gives out put like this

```
11:27 AM
11:47 AM
11:53 AM
12:13 PM
12:50 PM
02:02 PM
02:47 PM
03:04 PM
03:16 PM
```

When i try this query into using linq

```
public ViewResult Index1(DateTime? Startdate) 
{ 
    Startdate = DateTime.Now.Date; 
    var fm = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"); 
    var qr = from item in db.BookingArriveds 
             where item.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == Startdate 
             orderby DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 " +
             item.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime.ToString()) 
             select item; 
     return View(qr);
}
```

but it gives error like this

> *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.*

where is wrong and I need help for how to rewrite  above sql query to linq query also casting from varchar to datetime in linq?

Comment: You're trying to write a query which will be executed in the SQL but you're using C# methods like `DateTime.Parse()`, SQL doesn't recognize them.

Comment: ok omri , but how write this query in linq?

Comment: Why not parse it later? You can order by `item.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime` anyway since the prefix date that you're using is the same, so ordering without it using only date should provide the same results.

Comment: i tried  but it gives result like 11pm,10am,7pm,6am it is sorted on number only not sorted based on am/pm

Comment: What's the difference between `BookingArrivedEnquiredTime` and `BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime`?

Comment: @dan BookingArrivedEnquiredTime it is time and datatype is string,and BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime it is date and time and datatype is datetime

Comment: So................  do you think maybe instead of creating an entirely new DateTime (e.g. DateTime.Parse), you might use the one you already have...

Comment: @deo could you pleas rewrite the linq query based on above sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

you can do the casting and sorting on client:

```
db.BookingArriveds
  .Where(item => item.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == Startdate)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy(item => DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 " + item.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime);
```

or you can use SqlFunctions.DatePart to do the cast in Sql server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: DatePart function is not suitable, because it gives you only date part. To do the casting in SQL server, you should define your own sql function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456847(v=vs.100).aspx

The question is, why are you storing `BookingArrivedEnquiredTime` in a varchar column. I believe it should be part of `BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime` or it should be stored as integer or numeric column

Comment: --->i tried your query it's working fine it is sorting am to pm but it not sorted the after 12 i will give sample out put here--> 12:48 AM
06:02 AM
07:06 AM
08:41 AM
09:41 AM
12:38 PM
06:02 PM
07:06 PM
08:41 PM

Comment: I don't see problem in the output. It is sorted as it should be.
12:38PM -> 12:38; 6:02PM -> 18:02, etc..

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, this breaks because .ToString fails to translate to relevant SQL on the way into the database.

However, Microsoft provides the [SqlFunctions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is a collection of methods that can be used in situations like this.

For this case, what you are looking for here is [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public ViewResult Index1(DateTime? Startdate) 
{ 
    Startdate = DateTime.Now.Date; 
    var fm = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"); 
    var qr = from item in db.BookingArriveds 
             where item.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == Startdate 
             orderby SqlFunctions.StringConvert("01/01/2000 " +
             item.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime.ToString()) 
             select item; 
     return View(qr);
}
```

Good when the solution with temporary variables is not desirable for whatever reasons.

Comment: this does alphabetical sorting on string field, which is wrong. He need to convert BookingArrivedEnquiredTime to datetime

Comment: My working code is helps to resolve the error only !